# VueJS not setting properties after ajax call in mounted function

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Im experimenting with VueJS and I have the following code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    test: { }
},
methods: {
    getAttributes: function(){

        var pseudoThis = this;

        $.get('/api/getSpecifications').done(function(resp){
            pseudoThis.test = resp;
            console.log(resp);
        });

    }
},
mounted: function(){
    this.getAttributes();
}
});
```

The ajax call gets executed, and i get json results. However the property test always stays {} , no matter what i try.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Edit:

Did some more testing, and also made a Fiddle with a copy of my current code:
https://jsfiddle.net/cfhLg35v/2/

In the fiddle everything works as expected, so it seems to be a local issue. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please do console.log(pseudoThis) you may get hint as to what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
getAttributes () {
        $.get('/api/getSpecifications').done((resp) => {
            this.test = resp;
            console.log(resp);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Same results, property isn't getting filled.

Comment: I've made a fiddle with a copy of my code, and there it does work. So it seems to be a local issue. Got any idea's ? https://jsfiddle.net/cfhLg35v/2/